# NFA not accepting a certain string

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I am trying to make a non-deterministic NFA that does not contain a string "101".

How do I make my NFA so that it does not have this string?

My attempt:

[image]

Comment: The DFA only needs 3 states. NFA isn't simpler.

Comment: I'm aware of that but I'm still requiring help on how to do NFA's of this manner

Comment: Why? Every DFA is an NFA.

Comment: I am currently solving exercises on creating NFAs, the second part would be translating them into DFAs. I asked this question because I do not know how to handle anything that does NOT include something

Comment: For complementation, just convert to DFA and it will be straightforward. And it is supposed to be exponentially large and nowhere like the original NFA.

Comment: Rather than give a diagram, you should try to explain how you proceed, following what idea.

Comment: In other words, you want an automaton for $\Sigma^* \setminus \{101\}$? I agree with babou: it is impossible do glean from your image what your concept was. In particular, there isn't even an explicit path for $101$!

Comment: @user23013 "And it is supposed to be exponentially large and nowhere like the original NFA." -- that is not an accurate general statement. The DFA *can* be large and very unlike the input NFA but it certainly does not have to be.

Comment: To be clear: this question currently lacks precision. A trivial automaton for $\emptyset$ solves the problem as stated; you probably want to edit it to say "everything but $101$" or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a recipe for constructing automata for $\Sigma^* \setminus F$ for any regular $F \subseteq \Sigma^*$.

1. Construct a (complete) DFA $A_F$ for $F$.
2. Construct the complement automaton $\overline{A_F}$.
3. Optional: minimise.

The first step is particularly easy (if maybe time consuming) for finite $F$. The second one is standard (flip accepting and non-accepting states) and should be covered by any textbook on this subject.

Of course, step 1 may blow up the size of the automaton (going from an easy-to-design NFA to DFA); this can in particular be the case for finite sets. In your particular case, though, you never get more than five states.

Comment: sorry this is a multiple part homework and from there it wants me to proceed in the path: 1. create NFA 2. change this nfa into a dfa 3. minimize which is why I'm not starting from 1. Construct a complete DFA.
While I do realise how to achieve everything else, I'm just confused at doing the does not contain a "101" part.

Comment: @KadanaKanz To be frank, for the purpose of this site I don't care much for artificial constraints such as this. As user23013 aptly comments, if you start out at 1) with a DFA (which is formally correct, provided your professor does not use weird definitions), the remaining subexercises are trivial. As a TA, I'd consider this the more elegant solution, in particular because you get the correctness proof basically for free (following my approach, assuming $A_F$ is suitably simple).

Comment: thank you for your comments, I have created a DFA but I may have another problem which I'm hoping to try it before asking again.